# Change title of Mac OS X Mavericks app

Tags: osx-mavericks

I need to change some aspect of the title bar in a Cocoa App on Mavericks. I don't own the App or have access to the source. The change could be to change the title text, or the color of the bar. I want the change to apply only to this 1 app.

Is this possible?

thanks,

-joe

Comment: Not the best place to ask, but go to your application folder and hit enter while the item is highlighted and then you can rename.

Answer (score 0):

Go to your Applications folder and highlight the application you wish to change. Then press enter and you'll see it "blinking" and highlighted. Just type what you want to name it to and you're all set. Also you might want to ask here next time. https://apple.stackexchange.com/

Comment: I didn't explain the problem clearly. I don't want to change the name of the app wrapper. I need to change the title that appears in the title bar on the main window of the application.

Comment: I'm not sure if thats possible but I recommend you play around with the Info.plist.